# Ionic 1: make ion-nav-bar fixed, not update between views

Tags: javascript, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a very simple **Ionic 1** app, where my I want `ion-nav-bar` to be fixed, always the same, displaying a logo as a title of every view.

Regarding to the [ionNavBar docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBar/) the usage of this directive should be the following:

```
<body ng-app="starter">
  <!-- The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate -->
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <!-- where the initial view template will be rendered -->
  <ion-nav-view>
    <ion-view>
      <ion-content>Hello!</ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

My app's `index.html` `<body>` looks much the same:

```
<body ng-app="adidasApp">

  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-title>
      <img src="img/my-logo.png">
    </ion-nav-title>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view>
  </ion-nav-view>

</body>
```

As the docs point out

> The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate

the nav bar will be updated as we navigate. This makes my image to fade, to feel like it is loading every time I change between views.

But I don't want this to happen. I would like my image to stay still all the time, without updating each time I change views. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ion-header-bar` directive that adds a fixed header bar above some content: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionHeaderBar/

Keep rocking!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Keep rocking! 